# What does "account" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Procedures to **Account** for Workers
>
> Managers are responsible for **accounting** for all workers in their
>   department. He/She shall report anyone **unaccounted** for to the emergency department
>   via radio.

It describes how managers should act in the event of emergency (fire, chemical spills, and etc.). I looked up dictionaries, and it seems that "account" here means "(noun) a written or spoken description of an event", but "account" here is used as a verb, and the meaning of the dictionary only fits for noun. The only meaning for the verb "account" is:

> to think of someone or something in the stated way
>   (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account)

Then, should I interpret "account" as "report"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning here isn't found in the Cambridge learner's dictionary, but it is in wiktionary.  It is the [eighth sense of the verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/account#Verb)

> 8 (intransitive) To establish the location for someone. [from 19th c.]
>   *After the crash, not all passengers were accounted for.*

So in an emergency, managers must find where all their workers are located, and report anyone that they can't find using the radio.